# How can I check PDF/UA compliance?

Tags: pdf

While there are lot of posts on how to check PDF/A compliance but seemingly there are no posts about testing PDF/UA compliance.
I checked in Acrobat Pro even, we cannot verify PDF/UA compliance through that software.
The only nearest tool which I could find was PAC (PDF accessibility checker).
But I am not sure if that is sufficient for UA compliance.

Is there any tool which you know that can do this job ?

Comment: there's an online validator at pdf-tools.com, has a lot of options, not sure about /UA exactly, but worth a look

Answer (score 1):

If you run the validation for the "a" variants of PDF/A (PDF/A-1a, PDF/A-2a, etc.) and it passes you'll know if the PDF meets the structural requirements for PDF/UA. However, the machine validators really can't address the semantic requirements...

- Complete tagging of "real content" in logical reading order
- Tags must correctly represent the document's semantic structures (headings, lists, tables, etc.)
- Problematic content is prohibited, including illogical headings, the use of color/contrast to convey information, inaccessible JavaScript, and more
- Meaningful graphics must include alternative text descriptions